# Updating PHP on Solaris: Compilation errors

Tags: php, makefile, solaris, configure

I am trying to update PHP 5.3.6 to 5.6.13 on SunOS. 
I downloaded php-5.6.13.tar.gz, unpacked it, ran

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-opcache=no
```

and then I tried to run

```
make
```

But after several warnings like

```
"/tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/sljit/sljitNativeSPARC_common.c", line 1399: warning: integer overflow detected: op "<<"
"/tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.c", line 1523: warning: no explicit type given
"/tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.c", line 1523: syntax error before or at: int
```

the installation stops with the following error:

```
"/tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.c", line 9622: syntax error before or at: void
cc: acomp failed for /tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.c
*** Error code 1
```

Same thing with gmake:

```
"/tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.c", line 9622: syntax error before or at: void
cc: acomp failed for /tmp/php-5.6.13/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.c
gmake: *** [ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_jit_compile.lo] Error 1
```

I am no unix admin, I simply need to update PHP in order to run the latest MySQL.

What am I doing wrong ?

I am following this procedure: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2000/11/17/php_admin.html?page=2

Comment: First, try using `gmake` instead of `make`.

Comment: -bash: gmake: command not found

Comment: What version of Solaris?  `gmake` could be in `/usr/sfw/bin` or something similar.

Comment: Found it in /usr/sfw/bin. Same problem, I updated the OP

Comment: Which version of Solaris?  I've had issues recently building yasm on Solaris 11.2 where `configure` failed to properly pass the `-std=c99` argument to GCC.

Comment: Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10s_u10wos_17b SPARC

Comment: How up-to-date is your version of GCC?  If that's up-to-date, you're going to have to dig into the make process and figure out why it's failing.

Comment: What account shoul one use to install PHP ?

Comment: Depends on where you want to install it - you'll need write access to the installation location.  But that's moot until you get it to compile on your system.